# Number with decimal input in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, decimal

I have a number input within a React component, and it needs to accept numbers with a decimal point. Usually, entries will be in the fractions of a cent, like `0.0073`, that kind of thing.

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="rate" className="col-sm-6 control-label">Rate:</label>
  <div className="col-sm-2"> 
    <input type="number"
      title="Rate"
      id="rate"
      className="form-control"
      value={this.props.rate}
      min="0.00"
      step="0.001"
      max="1.00"
      onChange={()=>{
        console.log('page rate changed');
        this.props.setrate($('#rate').val());
      }} />
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that with every keystroke, it's resetting the rate for the app, and then putting that value into the `input`. So it goes like this:

- User types `0`, the value is set to `0`, and `0` is displayed.
- User types `.`, `0.` isn't a valid number, so the input is cleared.

Can anyone think of a workaround? I know I could just use a normal input, but `type="number"` leads to some nice stuff in various browsers.

Comment: Can you post a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/972umnnq/

Comment: Please note that it's not recommended using JQuery with React. Your onChange handler should look something like: `onChange={this.setPercentage}` and in your component define `setPercentage(e){ let value = e.currentTarget.value; /* code here to ensure its a percentage */ this.setState({ percentage: value }) }` when you change the value of this field your this.state.percentage object will change. Dont forget to set `this.setPercentage = this.setPercentage.bind(this);` in your constructor usually after `this.state = {}` is defined so that your setPercentage function can access `this.setState`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've tried your code and wasn't really affected by your issue, the value is indeed empty when you type the last dot, but the input is not reset.

The thing I changed from your implementation is that I get the input value from the `onChange` event rather than use jQuery.

```js
<input onChange={e => this.props.setrate(e.target.value)} />
```

But I doubt your issue comes from that though.

What you could do is not to call your `setrate` function when you detect an ending dot in your string. Your state will not be modified until the user types a valid number, so one keystroke after the `0.`.

```js
<input onChange={e => {
  const str = e.target.value
  if (str.charAt(str.length - 1) === '.') { return }
  this.props.setrate(str)
}} />
```

Comment: I think my issue might be that I was using `value` instead of `defaultValue`. Thank you for showing me how to do this without jQuery though - it's kind of a crutch I'm trying to get rid of with React.

Comment: I voted this down as I can still recreate the problem myself.  Setting defaultValue keeps the problem for occurring but it doesn't give you the nicely formatted value a user make expect.

Answer (score 8):

```
    <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.rate}
        onChange={this.onAmountChange}
      />
```

type should be text and input value should be defined by regex.

```
onAmountChange = e => {
    const amount = e.target.value;

    if (!amount || amount.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,4})?$/)) {
      this.setState(() => ({ amount }));
    }
  };
```

regex here means: start with a number and add as many as you want. then optionally end with decimal numbers up to 4 decimals.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```js
const floatRegExp = new RegExp('^[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$')

const handleValidationOnChange = (e, v, onChange) => {
  const { value } = v
  if (value === '' || floatRegExp.test(value)) {
    onChange(e, v)
  }
}

const InputFloat = props => {
  if (typeof props.onChange !== 'function') {
    return <Form.Input { ...props } />
  }

  const { onChange, ...parentProps } = props

  return <Form.Input
    { ...parentProps }
    onChange={(e, v) => handleValidationOnChange(e, v, onChange)}
  />
}
```

Form.Input can be any Component that has a value.

You will have to later check for '', that is unavoidable.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="number"
      title="Rate"
      id="rate"
      className="form-control"
      value={this.props.rate}
      min="0.00"
      step="0.001"
      max="1.00"
      presicion={2}   //very important
      onChange={()=>{
        console.log('page rate changed');
        this.props.setrate($('#rate').val());
      }} />
```

Comment: `$('#rate').val()`!?!?! What about using `event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` and get the target value?

Comment: is that JQuery mixed with React? 

Comment: @Emaborsa This is about getting precision in a straightforward way, why get complicated interacting with the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

```
{(text) => this.setState({ value: text.replace( /^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[^0-9]+$/, ''),    })}
```

This will replace any input on runtime if there is any input except decimal number

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where I had decimal numbers in a database and reading them into React. By default, the decimal would show up with trailing zeroes when displaying in React. Trying to display without the trailing zeroes gave me the issue that you describe above. My issue may be slightly different from what you are looking for, but I think it would help others. What I had to do:

- Pull the data from the database with the desired formatting. For example: instead of `select mynumber from mytable` I did `select (TRIM(mynumber)+0) as mynumber from mytable`. This automatically removes the trailing zeroes.
- I then read these values into the React JS script and set in state. These become the `value` of the input fields.
- Then rather than preventing users from entering a non-number value I simply change the background color of the input field to red if the value is not a number.

  if (isNaN(mynumber)) {
      bgcolor = "#fdd" //Add this to your input style
  }
- I found the red background above good enough for my purposes but you can also implement an additional check when the user clicks the save button.

Comment: This is not related to REACT